# Why is a multiple defined to require an integer?

Tags: terminology, math-history, integers

Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_(mathematics)), a multiple is the product of any quantity and an integer. The requirement for an integer strikes me as subjective. Why do we define a multiple in a manner that require an integer be present in the multiplication step.

Comment: If we allow ourselves to expand to all of real or complex numbers, every number is a multiple of every nonzero number. It pretty much loses all meaning.

Comment: *Where* in Wikipedia? Link? Context? Of course there is a more general concept of multiple in ring theory.

Comment: Euclid's [*Elements*](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookV/bookV.html#defs), **Bk.V** Definition 2 "The greater is a *multiple* of the less when it is measured by the less" where "measuring" means exactly to count how many times the "unit length" rod is contained into the measured length.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1210034/definition-of-multiple?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a shorthand way of saying "integral multiple". If something occurs "multiple times", it typically means "a whole number of times". It's just quicker and easier to speak of a "multiple" of something rather than "a positive integral multiple" (that's too wordy).

There are of course other types of multiples, for example:

- a rational multiple of pi
- a scalar multiple of a vector
- a real multiple of a complex number